Plausible orbit to have a visible object slowly circle over the night sky
I want to have the inhabitants of a particular world - doesn't have to be a planet, can be a moon - be able to see a certain point of light - can be a planet, moon, star, whatever - moving in the sky in such a way that tracking its position will show it regularly moving in a circle across the sky. So what I mean by this is that if you come back at the same time every night the light should always be visible, but moving very slightly, such that after some long period of time - say, 200 years - its plotted positions would form a full circle over the fixed stars. What sort of plausible orbit would produce this effect? Can be a binary star system, something to do with moons, planetary tilt, whatever. I just want this to be a way that you could track time on the ground with a kind of stonehenge like building where the star will be exactly above a specific stone in the circle (at a given time of night) at a given point in its cycle, rotating around the full circle over the Earth equivalent of decades.

??? Our Sun does that, with a cycle of one year. (Well, almost. Instead of a closed circle, it comes just a tiny little bit west of where it should have been, by a little less than one minute of arc. The northward equinox make a full cycle in about 26,000 years.)

@AlexP but sun moves across sky during the day. It doesn’t move in a circle over one hemisphere. I think the question calls for equivalent of a star orbiting Polaris.

(or something far simpler, as noted in my answer)

If I understand you... If people had a star map of their hemisphere and plotted the course of this light over the course of 200 years it would draw a circle on the star map, right?

Sooooooooooo. This happens after Creation Day #1: there is daylight and there is darkness. Are there luminaries, too? A greater one to give daylight? If so, there is no way to avoid a wandering spot of light spending half its years in daylight. If that's OK, then your world is Earth and your night lamp is a mix of Saturn (apparent magnitude ~0) and Neptune (orbital period ~165yrs).

You can use Lagrange Points and a comet.
Now, L2, which is the only point on the night side is unstable. This means that a comet caught there will eventually escape. L4 and L5 are stable, however, they are positioned sunwards for your planet.
We can add another planet with a wider orbit than your main planet. Then make its orbital period the same (it takes the same amount of time for both planets to circle the sun). Lastly, offset their positions so that the farther planet's L4 or L5 is directly behind your main planet.
With this setup, a comet can be caught for a long period of time in a stable Lagrange Point on the night side of your planet. If it's slightly offset so that the sun can shine on it (it is not always in your planet's shadow) it will develop a Coma or tail and be bright in your night sky.
Objects in Lagrange Points also tend to orbit the point itself, so if that period is long enough, you will see a circular motion over some time.
Edit
In response to some of the comments, I ran the numbers through the orbital period calculations in order to get a planet that is further away but retains the same period.
Although it is possible, the planets would have to orbit a red dwarf as the sun is just too big. Additionally, a planet the size of jupiter as the outer body only gains about 500,000km of orbital radius while maintaining the same period. It is still not very much. For comparison, the moon is 384,400km away.
The unfortunate consequence is that you planet with life would be basically in the L4 or L5 of the larger planet, not in front of it. You could make it work by further modifying the mass of the star to make it smaller, but it would affect life in your solar system.

Another planet with a wider orbit will have a longer orbital period — that’s how orbital mechanics works.

Make the planet bigger and it will orbit faster.

@JustAnotherUser: The orbital period depends only of the distance from the star. The mass of the planet is irrelevant.

@AlexP Period calculation according to Orbital Mechanics of two bodies. Denominator component of formula: G(M1 + M2)

@JustAnotherUser: Yeah, but when $M_2 \ll M_1$, $M_1 + M_2 \approx M_1$. And in practice, planets have very much lower mass than stars.

@AlexP Saying the mass is irrelevant without qualifying why, is bad science. Saying it can be negligible if the size of the star is very large compared to the planet is better. Giving the range of ratios where the mass can essentially be ignored is best.

L4/L5 are only stable if the mass in there is way less than masses of other celestial bodies AND there isn't any other celestial body interfering with the planet; your answer indicates that there are two planets orbiting around one star at the same, or slightly differing orbits. Also IIRC the "orbital" radius of a rock trapped in L4 or L5 is slightly lower than the planet's. But, if you'd be able to run two planets over one orbit, the other planet would do relative motions similar to those required.

The world is orbiting one of a binary pair of stars, with a 200 year period. There is a third star toward the axis of the binary (toward the north or south poles of the binary system), either a very distant third companion or simply an unusually close star with low proper motion, close enough that parallax makes it appear to take a circular path across the background stars.
Proper motion will actually cause it to follow a looping path across the sky instead of a perfect circle, and telescope observations will show the looping line to actually consist of smaller one-year loops, but with a 200 year period, the structure's not likely to be relevant for much more than 10-20 of the long loops.

Sirius, as seen from either WISE 0855-0714 or Procyon, would probably fit the bill. Sirius is the single brightest star in Earth's sky, Procyon and WISE 0855-0714 are only a little over half the distance to it that Sol is so it will appear 4 times as large and bright and have a very high proper motion and parallax so it will loop across the sky in a relatively short period of time.

This depiction of 20 stable 3 body problem solutions may provide an orbital set that suits.
Viewing highly recommended to all.
There are others. If one body other than your target world was luminous (by reflection or self illumination or ... , then you may see only one object, but having two may not hurt.
The second row first column canidate may be suitable.
In each case consider the effect of freezing one body in space and observing the other two.  Placing these systems at a stable lagrange point of a more distant star may be useful.
Here is a screen capture from the animation above.


A binary star system around the planet's north pole
There's a serious issue with the question: You want the observer to use solar clock to determine "every night", but the star-based time shift against the sun-based time would cause the observer to have different stars directly above him. So, if an object would be located anywhere else but in the polar regions (depending on the planet's axial tilt) would eventually be not visible at some time of the year. Thus, to answer this question you are required that your object be first locked against the planet's axis of revolution, and not against its orbit, and second, it has to really move, while also being bright enough.
Therefore, the best candidate for an entity to provide such an effect will be a binary system, with one component be a bright visible star, and the other be a black hole, with the star's mass a lot less than the hole's, their orbital plane to be roughly perpendicular to the vector from the observer to the black hole (or rather the mass center), with the revolution period of 200 years. That vector should also align with the planetary axis, in order to retain visibility of that star over all the 200-year long period of nights from the observer's position (best viewed from 45 degrees latitude on one of the hemispheres).
There seem to be plausible solutions in term of visible parallax of the star in that binary viewed from that planet, this calculator displays a major semi-axis great enough to detect that the star moves while keeping the black hole's mass low enough to not influence the original star system; yet it doesn't seem to be great enough. Say I've input 1200 suns for the BH and up to 30 suns for the star (oh hey a RED GIANT), and came up with a major semi-axis of 360AU - pretty big, but if viewed from a mere 1 light year, it corresponds to the star's visible parallax of 2\*arcsin(360AU/1LY) ~ 2\*arcsin(0.0057) ~ 0.64 degrees or 38 arc minutes. Placing the planet closer might cause destructive effects, including effective orbiting around the black hole, although not as visible (at 1LY a sun would orbit a BH of 1200 suns over 458000 years), but crucial to the world's prolonged existence.
As a side note, you might replace the binary system with a star orbiting the galaxy's central SMBH off the galaxy plane, like S2 in our Milky Way but brighter and farther, but there should be difficulties calling that star close to polar, as the planet's system will also orbit that SMBH at a period, causing all the "fixed stars" to change positions, and the parallax of that S2-like star would be imperceptible without a good telescope if the planet's system would be far enough to call stars "fixed".

There are one relatively straight-forward answer and one where it would not be the night sky but the Sun itself
A (distant) giant planet with 200 years orbit
Any planet around the central star with a 200 year orbit period would fulfill the criterion.
"... mean by this is that if you come back at the same time every night the light should always be visible, but moving very slightly, such that after some long period of time - say, 200 years - its plotted positions would form a full circle over the fixed stars." The highlighted part is the important one as it makes clear that we do not talk about the apparent path during one day (thus revolution of the body the observer is standing on).
In the Solar system such orbit with 200 years would be somewhere between Neptun and Pluto. If you make the planet big enough (e.g. Jupiter-like or even slightly bigger) you can make it a somewhat brighter dot than current Neptune (which is not visible by naked eye from Earth due to the distance). You might even go as far as make that object as big as a small Brown dwarf. Making it another star (thus similar size and brightness as the Sun) would mess-up the stability of the solar system overall, though and this analogy would break down.
The observer's planet has an orbital period of 200 Earth years length
Another solution which would make that 200-year object the brightest object itself would be to place your observer on such a distant planet itself. If you take a solar-type star and orbit it in 200 years, the planet would be very icy (-200°C).
However, take a bigger star, and orbit it in 200 years and conditions might become more favourable: Increase the size and thus luminosity of the central star itself. E.g. put yourself around a 200-year orbit of a star ~8 times as heavy as our Sun. Then an orbital distance around twice as far as Neptune would get a bit less light as Earth does and it would take about ~200 years to orbit it.
